# Java - finding the variance - would this work?

Tags: java, variance

Link to exercise: mooc.cs.helsinki.fi/programming-part1/material-2013/week-3?noredirect=1#e67

Would this work? I feel like my math is correct, but I can't test my code because I'm at work.

---

### **SUM:**

```
int a = 0;
int sum = 0;

while (a < list.size()) {
sum += list.get(a);
a++;
}
return sum;
```

---

### **AVERAGE:**

```
double average = sum(list)/list.size();

return average;
```

---

### **VARIANCE:**

```
int a = 0;
double b = list.get(a) - average(list);
double sum = 0;

while (a < list.size()) {
sum += Math.pow(b, 2);
a++;
}
double variance = sum / (list.size() - 1);
return variance;
```

Would that work?

**FOLLOW UP QUESTION:**

This is apparently the "correct" way to do it...

```
double sumDiffSquared = 0.0;
double avg = average(list);

for (int value : list) {
double difference = value - avg;
difference *= difference;
sumDiffSquared += difference;
double variance = difference / (list.size() - 1);
}
return variance;
```

---

Okay so I THINK I understand most of it (notes below)...

double difference = value - avg;

**Everything from "list" was put into the variable "value" and now we are subtracting the previously calculated average from each number within the variable "value" one-by-one and putting the new values into the variable "difference". Makes perfect sense.**

difference *= difference;

**We are now multiplying each number within the variable "difference" by itself. Once again, one-by-one. Makes sense.**

Here's where I get lost...

sumDiffSquared += difference

**This is what makes no sense to me. Why/how does this add the values together? To me it looks like the value of the variable "sumDiffSquared" is 0, so this would just be adding 0 to each of the values in the variable "difference"...**

Comment: huh... Open excel (or equivalent) - enter a few random numbers - calculate variance - run your code on the same numbers - compare?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `sumDiffSquared` does not get reset for each loop, therefore it is accumulating the value of `difference` for each loop.